# jQuery Array contains File object

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
  function generateFileArea() {
     fileDialog.on('change', function (event) {
        console.log('File dialog changed.');

        var fileHeaderHTMLElement = $('#file-names-wrapper');

        fileHeaderHTMLElement.css('visibility', 'visible');

        readOnlyFiles = fileDialog[0].files;//<= File objects

        //

        for(index = 0; index < readOnlyFiles.length; index++){
            if($.inArray(readOnlyFiles[index], files) > -1){ // <== always -1
                console.log('This file is already in the array.');
                continue;
            }

            // console.log(jQuery.inArray(readOnlyFiles[index], files));

            files.push(readOnlyFiles[index]);
        }

        console.log(files);

        if (files.length == 0)
            return;

        fileNamesTable.empty();//<= this is a list

        for(index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
            createFileButton(files[index]);
        }
   });
}
```

How can I make it so that the `inArray` function won't return `-1` each time I'm verifying that the file is a duplicate. Is it possible to compare `File` objects inside the `Array` so that I can avoid adding duplicates to the array?

Answer (score 0):

It's a deceptively complex question.

Consider you have a scenario where two files are almost identical except for a single character difference between the files.

When JavaScript is performing a inArray function with some basic strings, it is able to compare every single letter to ensure the data is the same.

With files however, JavaScript won't let you accidentally perform a letter-by-letter comparison of files because of how extreme the comparison would be in terms of processing.

In these instances (in fact, with all objects in general) the data is summarised as `[File]` or `[Object]` or something.

That said, you need a way to re-enable comparison of the files.

You'll need to modify your approach slightly.

You could, for example, **compare the MD5 hashes of the files**. MD5 is designed to convert an entire file into a short 32 letter string. It's kind of like a 'summary' of the file's contents. If you change a single letter of the file and perform the MD5 on it, the whole MD5 hash will change.

This allows you to compare files with a very low risk of "collision" (where two completely different files will have the same MD5 hash. I must stress this happens VERY rarely)

Alternatively, you could **assert that files with the same filename are the same file** - but this may not work for your implementation or product. For example, this solution may be intended to accept 10 files all with the same name.

However if filenames was considered sufficient to tell two files apart, just keep a secondary array alongside `readOnlyFiles` (maybe something like `readOnlyFilenames`) and use that for the comparison. You just need to make sure the arrays are kept in-sync. If you remove an element from one, you must remove it from the other. This allows you to have a lookup table of file data vs. file names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes a lot of sense. I've added this code in the `for` loop, but it keeps showing me the same checksum even if the files are different.

 `for(index = 0; index < readOnlyFiles.length; index++){

            md5 = $.md5(readOnlyFiles[index]).toString();

            console.log(md5);

        }`

Comment: Based on that explanation, my thinking is that your hash function is just comparing the word '[File]' rather than attempting to read the binary data. Perhaps storing the contents of the file into an array is converting the file to strings. Play around, try and get some real file data showing in the console. If you can do that, you should be able to throw it at an MD5 function no problem

Comment: Also my apologies, I neglected to supply you with an MD5 JS library... but it seems you found a jQuery addon which looks ideal. Always nice to see a StackOverflow user actually considering the answers and their implementation - rather than insisting on some code which could be copy pasted, followed by complaining it didn't work because they didn't read the instructions :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me edit my previous comments for some reason. Anyway, you may want to consider the FileReader HTML5 API's for actually getting the contents of the file. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader (e.g. `FileReader.readAsText()`)

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple solutions, such as using `==` and `===` operators, I've come up with the solution to compare the sizes and names of the files I already have in my array with the one I want to push into the array.

```
for(index = 0; index < readOnlyFiles.length; index++){
        wasFound = false;

        if(files.length > 0)
            for(secondIndex = 0; secondIndex < files.length; secondIndex ++){
                if(files[secondIndex].name == readOnlyFiles[index].name &&
                    files[secondIndex].size == readOnlyFiles[index].size){
                    wasFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(wasFound === true){
                console.log('Already in the file list');
                continue;
            }

        files.push(readOnlyFiles[index]);
    }
```

Comment: What if two files have the same filesize and filename - but have completely different contents? This solution would work, but its very vulnerable to exploits and collisions.